# user lacks privilege or object not found exception

Tags: java, mysql

I want to get a nickname and a password from the user but my code does not work.
I created an access database which have StudentPassword table . This table have two columns which are NickName and Password . Also , I created a insertStudentPassword method and StudentPassword class.

```
public static void initialize() throws Exception
{
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Enes Kalkan/workspace/HW3_4/HW_DB.accdb");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}
public static void insertStudentPassword(StudentPassword S) throws Exception
{
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into [StudentPassword] (NickName,Password) "+"values ('"+S.nickname+"','"+S.password+"');");
}
```

My StudentPassword constructor is below:

```
public StudentPassword(String n,String p)
{
    this.nickname=n;
    this.password=p;
}
```

There is no any syntax error my code but when I enter a nick name and password, I receive this exception : user lacks privilege or object not found: NICKNAME

I don't understand why I receive this . Thank you for any support.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: there are  two columns  NickName and Password as short text

Answer (score 0):

This is a database access issue.
Check what is the user account that you use to authenticate to the database when issuing the query from your question. Then check what are the access rights of this user - you may be missing the UPDATE privilege, or even some more.

Comment: In that database , there are different tables. I can reach them but in StudentPassword table , there is this error

Comment: Great, but database privileges are issued per table. So access to other tables does not imply access to **this** table. Also, what type of 'reaching' the other tables do you mean (because your problem with StudentPassword is not about generally 'reaching' it, but about specifically UPDATING it) ?

Comment: Thank you for support . I handled this problem . My studentpassword table has NickName column. Problem is about name of the column . Method is searching 'NICKNAME' but mine NickName . There is discrepancy between 'I' and 'i'.